# Clarification on an earlier post (Processing top N lines from an input file)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to create a mapper which processes only the first k lines in the input file. I came across this post:

[Hadoop-> Mapper->How can we read only Top N rows from each file from given input path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009648/hadoop-mapper-how-can-we-read-only-top-n-rows-from-each-file-from-given-input)
It says that override the run method as below:

```
@Override
public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  setup(context);

  int rows = 0;
  while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
    if (rows++ == 10) {
      break;
    }

    map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
  }

  cleanup(context);
}
```

So I tried the solution but the compiler isn't able to find "Context" and "setup()" I tried importing org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.* but doesn't work
Also can anyone explain the arguments in the map() function?

Sample code

```
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> 
{
    @Override
    public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException //for reading the first k lines only
    {
        setup(context);

        int k = 5;

        int rows = 0;
        while (context.nextKeyValue()) 
        {
            if (rows++ == k)        break;
                map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
        }

        cleanup(context);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you extending the Mapper class? Pls post ur complete class (or at least the extends part).

Comment: @Jasper  I am implementing the Mapper Class. Please see the edited part.

Answer (score 0):

You are not extending the Mapper Class.

It should be like this for eg:

> MyMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>

See an example here: 
http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount 
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/map/MultithreadedMapper.html (This has override run part too)